How to load a function from a Vim9 script and call it?
If I save this simple script in a file:
vim9script
def Hi()
    echo "Hello"
enddef

And I try to load and run it:
:so %
:call Hi()

I get:
E117: Unknown function: Hi

Can anyone explain?
I thought I would be able to just write :Hi() because it says in the help that you can "Call function without :call" but that just results in an error:
E492: Not an editor command: Hi()

I guess I have to define a command to run it?
:command! HiThere Hi()


You just prefix the function name with g: -- for example:
vim9script
def g:Hi()
    echo "Hello"
enddef

Then your :call Hi() will work.
Note that the g: is not necessary for calling within your script. If you had just put:
Hi()

At the bottom of your script it would have worked too.

vim9script functions are script local by default unless you prepend func name with the g: -- def g:Hi().
Instead of global, you can mark functions as exported and access them from another vim9script file using import:
test.vim:
vim9script

export def Hello()
    echow "Hello world!"
enddef


test-use.vim:
vim9script

import "./test.vim"

test.Hello()

